# syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (except the syntax is actually okay...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting a syntax error with what you see below.
What's weird is if I run: `ruby -c controllers/posts_controller.rb` I get back `Syntax OK`... I'm not sure exactly what's causing this to occur.. All of my definitions and classes are closed with "end" and from what I can tell it's all cased the same. What gives?

Syntax Error: `/home/action/workspace/zjmw00.5/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input`

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    # Create a private definition to secure the post parameters and then link it to create.
    # Make sure all private definitions are at the bottom so that your others aren't private.

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
        @post = Post.find(1, 2, 3)
    end

    private
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
        end
end
```

views/posts/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.title %></td>
      <td><%= post.text %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**

New error: `/home/action/workspace/zjmw00.5/app/models/post.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end`

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @post.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.title %></td>
      <td><%= post.text %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

posts_controller.erb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
        def new
        end

        # Create a private definition to secure the post parameters and then link it to create.
        # Make sure all private definitions are at the bottom so that your others aren't private.

        def create
                @post = Post.new(post_params)
                @post.save
                redirect_to @post
        end

        def show
                @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        end

        def index
                @post = Post.all
        end

        private
                def post_params
                        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
                end
end
```

As requested (post.rb)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        validates :title, :text,
                  presence: true,
end
```

Comment: This is definitely wrong but it should raise a different error `Post.find(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Is that your complete code? Because I don't see a line 27 in your posts controller. What is on line 27?

Comment: Sorry, the Post.find(1, 2, 3) was just a test. It's actually supposed to say Post.all
 - 
And yes, that's the whole file.

And posts.each should be post.each in the index - just forgot to change it back.

Please see edited section.

Comment: Post your post model.

Comment: you have a trailing comma after `presence: true`

Answer (score 1):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        validates :title, :text,
                  presence: true
end
```

Removing the trailing comma on presence: true - fixed the problem entirely.